# Convert two dimensional array to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a simple way/javascript to automatic convert an array like

```
[[7580,12.7],[6937,15]];
```

into this

```
[{x: 12.7,y: 7580,}, {x: 15, y: 6937,}],
```

Comment: Show us what have u done, which language u used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.prototype.map()

Code:

```js
const arr = [[7580,12.7],[6937,15]];
const result = arr.map(elem => ({
  x: elem[1],
  y: elem[0]
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like this:

```js
const input = [[7580,12.7],[6937,15]]

const output = input.map(([y , x]) => ({ x, y }))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` to return a new `array` where every item is of the type you want.

```js
function convert(list) {
  return list.map(function(item) {
    return { x: item[1], y: item[0] };
  });
}

console.log(convert([[7580, 12.7], [6937, 15]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map() function and return the object which represents the x,y value like this code

```
var arr=[[7580,12.7],[6937,15]];
var result = arr.map(function(v,i){
    return obj={
        x:v[1],
        y:v[0]
    };
});
console.log(result);
```